# How to use variable outside the function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

i am using JavaScript to display an event calender. I want to show all the events dynamically. I have to fetch the values using ajax. The value is properly printed in the function but I want to use these value variables outside the function.

my function is:-

```
$(function () {
    $("#calendar").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        beforeShowDay: checkBadDates
    });

});

function calendarnew(apdate) {
    dt = "";
    var myData = apdate.split(",");
    alert(myData);
    dt = myData.join('","');
    dt.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    return dt;
}

var $myBadDates = new Array("10 May 2014", "21 May 2014", "12 May 2014");

function checkBadDates(mydate) {
    var $return = true;
    var $returnclass = "available";
    $checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd MM yy', mydate);
    for (var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++) {
        if ($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate) {
            $return = false;
            $returnclass = "unavailable";
        }
    }
    return [$return, $returnclass];
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    calendarnew();
});

</script>
```

in this function how i use " dt " variable outside the function in the " $myBadDates ".
please, suggest me.

Comment: Assign `calendarnew()` to a variable? `var myVar = calendarnew(param)`

Answer (score 0):

Just define your variables out of function:

```
var x = null;

function f() {
    x = 2
}

f();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Hye, i am using it like:-
var dt="";
 function calendarnew(apdate)
 {
  
  var myData = apdate.split(",");
  alert(myData);
  dt=myData.join('","');
  dt.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  alert(dt);
  return dt;
 }

 calendarnew();
 alert(dt); 
but it can't work

Comment: Placing code with more than one line in a comment is not a good idea. But your commented code works as well, the only wrong thing is that you're calling `calendarnew();` without any argument, you should change it to `calendarnew('something');`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define and **scope** (with `var`) your variables outside the function eg:

```
var i = 0;
console.log(i);
function i_plus() {
    i++;
} 
i_plus();
console.log(i);
```

outputs to the console:

```
0
1
```

See here for more info on variable scopes in JavaScript:

[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)